# XCHG RAX, RAX: 0x09, what does this code do and how does it work?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86, decompilation, x86-64

Given the following short assembly snippet:

```
shr   rax, 3
adc   rax, 0
```

I worked this out a bit:

- We know `SHR` sets the CF with the last bit shifted.
- We know `ADC dest, 0` is just adding the CF.

So looking at the bits,

```
        128  64  32  16  8   4   2   1 
        8    7   6   5   4   3   2   1
        ------------------------------
        1    1   1   1   1   CF  X   X
CF=1 |  0    0   0   1   1   1   1   1  ; shr 3
```

So if we div 8 and add the CF the most correct function is something like this,

```
def f(x):
  return x//8  + int( (x//4) % 2 )
```

**When would that be useful.** Quickly testing it, I can see that I am right.

```
rax = 0  -> 0
rax = 1  -> 0
rax = 2  -> 0
rax = 3  -> 0

rax = 4  -> 1
rax = 7  -> 1
rax = 8  -> 1
rax = 11 -> 1

rax = 12 -> 2
rax = 13 -> 2
rax = 14 -> 2
rax = 15 -> 2
rax = 16 -> 2
rax = 17 -> 2
rax = 18 -> 2
rax = 19 -> 2

...

rax = 20 -> 3
rax = 28 -> 4
```

Decompilation with Radare is also not useful here,

```
int64_t entry0 (void) {
    rax >>= 3;
    __asm ("adc rax, 0");
}
```

My questions is, therefore, although I do understand the immediate impact these instructions have on the operand register, what is the higher level meaning of this instruction sequence?

---

This is [riddle `0x09`](https://www.xorpd.net/pages/xchg_rax/snip_09.html) from the [XCHG RAX, RAX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1502958082) book.

Comment: xchg rax,rax's puzzles are indeed nice. Is there a question here, though?

Comment: @NirIzr yes, quite clearly what's the answer to the riddle? "Riddle" means there is a something it's trying to demonstrate or do, or it has some utility and there is intent behind it. Any two instructions that the CPU can execute will do something (even if only waste time) why were these two instructions chosen?

Comment: I've figured out what the code does in the machine, but what's the use of that? What useful higher level thing can it be used to do?

Comment: Please put the thing you're asking about (`shr` and `adc` into the same register) in the title, not a book title.  Book title in the question body is plenty to make searches work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `shr rax, 3` is an unsigned divide by 8 with truncation **towards zero**. The inclusion of the `adc rax, 0` makes the division round to **nearest**  instead. (Though 0.5 will always be rounded up)

So this operation sets `RAX` to

- 1 if `RAX` is in the range of `[4-11]` (`8*1 ±4`)
- 2 if `RAX` is in the range of `[12-20]` (`8*2 ±4`)
- 3 if `RAX` is in the range of `[20-27]` (`8*3 ±4`)

You can simplify this further by reducing the shift to 1.

```
mov rax, 47  ; (remember 47/2 is 23.5)
shr rax, 1   ; rax = 23
adc rax, 0   ; rax = 24
```

If we do it again,

```
mov rax, 46  ; (remember 46/2 is 23)
shr rax, 1   ; rax = 23
adc rax, 0   ; rax = 23
```

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. I had considered the case of truncate-to-zero, and round-up. but I had not considered the case of nearest.